# how to add a group to adress book app with javascript on mac os

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, addressbook, javascript-automation

I try to import csv file in my contacts in a new group with javascript or applescript (I will appreciate help in JS).
what I've tried:(I tried lot combinaison of this command)

```
var contact = Application("Contacts");
var group = contact.Group({
'name':'test'})
var personne = contact.Person()


contact.add(contact.Person())
var g = contact.Group({name : "test"})
contact.add(g)
```

I tried first to create a new group but nothing become visible in adress book.app
I aim to do File -> new group(cmd+maj+n) and this new group file->import (cmd +o) but with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `push()` command to add an new object (**group**, **person**, ...) to the application.

Use the `save()` command to show the new object in the application.

This script add a new person in a new group:

```
var contact = Application("Contacts")

var g = contact.Group({name : "test"})
contact.groups.push(g)// add a new group to the application
contact.save() // save and show the group in the application


var personne = contact.Person({firstName : "Ben", lastName : "zzzzzz", organization : "abcd", jobTitle : "President"})
contact.people.push(personne)// add a new person to the application
contact.add(personne, {to : g}) // add personne to the group
contact.save() // save and show the new person in the new group
```

Comment: The first part of my problem is solved (add Group) : Thanks, but the personne is added to group and ~3s after the group become empty. did I have miss something?

Comment: I've investigated and saw that when disable all my accounts (settings, internet accounts, and I uncheck adress book for all account the script work perfectly). What can cause this bug?